# upper casing all values within quotes " " except those coming after certain words

Tags: python, regex, pandas, replace

I am trying to replace every word within quotes " " to upper case word except those coming after the word "then" in a pandas column:
for example:

```
0 There was a "quick" "brown" fox who "jumped" over the wall then "fell" and broke its "tooth"
```

the output should be:

```
0 There was a "QUICK" "BROWN" fox who "JUMPED" over the wall then "fell" and broke its "TOOTH"
```

although I am able to find the words in quotes but I am not able to exclude the word coming right after "then".

```
df.str.replace({r'"(.*?)"':r'\U$1') #this will select and replace all values in quotes to uppercase also values after then
```

please help.

Comment: Can you try `df.str.replace({r'(?<!then\s)"(\w*?)"':r'\U$1')`

Comment: thank you so much...It worked.could you also please mention resources where i can study more about regex ?.Thanks

Comment: I have added my suggestion as code below with links which i find useful. Hope these help you as well. Can you also update the exact `df.str.replace` code that you used finally to achieve your result? I am able to find the words using regex i put-in but i am not able to replace it the way you are doing it. So, if you can put it, i will also learn something :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex `(?<!then\s)"(\w*)"` to find the words within quotes that are NOT preceded by 'then' & 'space'

`"(\w*)"` = Look for words within quotes

`(?<!then\s)` = Make sure the words that are matched with `"(\w*)"`does not have 'then' & 'space' before it(Negative look-behind)

[RegexDemo](https://regex101.com/r/eUUkX5/4) You can see the demo of the regex here (you can put several other string to check how the regex works on them as well)

[Regex-info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) This is very comprehensive website (kind of the go-to website for all things regex) on regex, almost all concepts of regex should be answered here. It is not programming language dependent & has a lot of information which can be overwhelming.

[Regex Cheat-Sheet](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/regex-cheatsheet/) I would say start with this cheat sheet, it is very simple & explained in simple words. I find it very helpful.

Comment: That was very helpful ..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

String= He "ate" a "penguin" then "played with a hamburger.
 Turn the string into a list splitting at the word then. Convert the list[0] into a string, and use an if '"' is in clause to isolate the quoted words. Capitalize. Then split by spaces, use join to get the whole string back together again and there ya go